# Excel Makro to copy into another program

Tags: excel, vba

For my work i need to track what cases i did. Right now i note all the case numbers in an excel file where i also sort them to the categorie they belong. At the end of every week i then have to put in the numbers in our tracking tool with copy and paste (tracking tool isnt on the same desktop i work on so i cant do it directly)

So i thought maybe it would be possible to write a macro in the excel file that does the copy paste for me but i already fail when i want to switch from the excel to the tracking tool
I tried shell activate and windows activate but i only get run time errors

Im grateful for any help even different approches

Comment: Since these "the tracking tool" is abstract and we do not know anything about it, I am afraid that nobody can be of any help.

Comment: Maybe you could do something with `SendKeys`, but unless this tracking tool has an API it will be difficult to make a reliable macro to do this. You need to provide details if you want any help.

Comment: You could evaluate, if your tracking tool supports it, to use the [LUA language](https://www.lua.org). Excel is "easily" controllable with it.

Answer (score -1):

Please add screenshots and more explaination of the scenario so we could have better insights

Comment: This isn't an answer. Please don't use answers to post comments.